# Let $\phi: G \rightarrow G$ be given by $\phi(g)=g^2, g\in G$. Show that if $|G|$ is odd, then $\phi$ is an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $|G| < \infty$.

**Let $\phi: G \rightarrow G$ be given by $\phi(g)=g^2, g\in G$. Show that if $|G|$ is odd, then $\phi$ is an automorphism:**

I consider $a \in G$ and compute $\phi(g)=g^2=a \iff g = g^{-1}a$.

To show $\phi$ is bijective, I must show $\phi$ is surjective, since $\phi$ is an endomorphism:

But since multiplication by an element in a finite group is bijective there exists $a \in G$ such that $g^{-1}a = g$. It then follows that $\forall a \in G$ there exists $g$ such that $g^2 = a$.

I guess this is wrong. Since I don't use the fact that $|G|$ should be odd.

**Also I must prove that if $|G| = 35$ then $G$ is cyclic:**

I know $G$ has a unique Sylow-5-subgroup and Sylow-7-subgroup, so these are normal. Also these are cyclic, since they are of prime order.

So my idea is:

$\mathbb Z/35 \mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 7 \mathbb Z \cong Syl_5 \times Syl_7 \cong Syl_5 \cdot Syl_7 = \{xy | x \in Syl_5, y \in Syl_7 \}$.

The first equality follows from the CRT for groups, the second follows since groups of prime order are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$, the third since the Sylow-p-subgroups are normal and their intersection is equal to $e$ (consider order of elements).

Is this right ?

**Last let $p$ be a prime number. Show $G$ only has one Sylow-p-subgroup:**

The second Sylow theorem tells us that there exists $g \in G$ such that $gPg^{-1}=Q \Rightarrow gP = Qg = gQ \Rightarrow P=Q$

where I use the abelian property of $G$ and last multiplying by $g^{-1}$ on both sides.

Is there a simpler way of proving this ?

*Thanks.*

Comment: Your proof is of course wrong since you don't use the assumptions ...

Comment: But since multiplication by an element is bijective, is my proof right if I ignore that I should use the fact that $|G|$ is odd ?

Comment: Try to check the validity of your proof for $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $g^2=1_G$ for $g \neq 1_G$, then the set $\{1_G,g\}$ is the subgroup generated by $g$ and consists of $2$ elements.

This may happen only if $\mid G\mid$ is even, because the order of a subgroup always divides the order of the group.

So, if $\mid G\mid$ is odd, $\phi(g)=g^2=1_G$ only for $g=1_G$, i.e. the kernel of $\phi$ is trivial, hence $\phi$ is injective.

But an injective map between sets of the same finite cardinality is a bijection, thus $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

About the last questions, you got it right: in an abelian group conjugation is trivial and since Sylows are always conjugated one to another, there can be only one of them (for each prime divisor of the group order, of course).

Comment: Thanks Andrea, your answer reflect the theory I'm currently aware of ie. $\phi$ is injective iff. $\ker f = \{e\}$ - I should have been using that theorem.

Answer (score 4):

An isomorphism is an *invertible* homomorphism. Forget about bijecitivty, this is most often not the natural point of view (unfortunately, this is the only point of view which one learns in lectures and books ...).

If $G$ is a group of odd order, then $|G|$ and $2$ are coprime, i.e. there are integers $u,v$ such that $|G|u + 2 v=1$. Now show that $g \mapsto g^v$ is inverse to $g \mapsto g^2$.

By the way, this generalizes as follows: If $|G|$ and $n$ are coprime, then $g \mapsto g^n$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you, Martin. Would you also comment on the second question, you seem to have a pretty good grip on this.

Comment: Well you have to show that $G$ is the direct product of the two Sylow subgroups. This is quite formal, though, as soon as you know that they are normal and have the correct order etc.

Comment: So what I've done is right ? Was my way of showing that $\phi$ was a automorphism right, even though I ignored the size of $G$ being odd or even ?